# How to create dynamic path component in conjunction with retry until

Tags: karate

I have a use-case where I need to first call an API to get a list of ID's. From this response a random ID is chosen. Next I call a 2nd API which uses the random ID as a component in the path.

It's possible the 2nd API call can return an empty response, therefore I want to utilize `retry until` but use a different random ID in the path per retry iteration.

I've tried a couple of things:

First "in-lining" the JS function in the path to get a random ID:

```
Given path firstPart, myGetRandomId(idList), lastPart
And retry until response.length > 1
```

Second, tried putting the JS function in a `Examples:` as part of a `Scenario Outline:`

```
Given path firstPart, <ID>, lastPart
And retry until response.length > 1
Examples:
  | ID |
  | myGetRandomId(idList) |
```

The general issue I can't figure out is how to get the JS function to evaluate in either of this "in-line" kind of approaches.

And ideas/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that the Karate `retry until` works is that it will re-play the request *as-is* and you can't modify it.

So you have to take a different approach. Use a JS loop. Look at this example in the demos:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks.